# How do I enable iCloud Advanced Data Protection if one of my devices cannot be updated to the latest OS?

Tags: icloud

When attempting to enable Advanced Data Protection via iOS Settings.app, a "Update Your Devices" page is displayed saying that I need to update or remove a list of devices from my iCloud account.

One of them is a MacBook Pro using MacOS Monterey, which "...can't be updated to the latest version of MacOS. Remove from your account."

Does this mean that I can't enable Advanced Data Protection if I want to keep an old/incompatible device tied to my iCloud account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you must either update or remove all devices to enable Advanced Data Protection.

This is because those older devices don't understand how to communicate with the newly protected iCloud account.

---

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/security/sec973254c5f/web):

> Devices where the user is signed in with their Apple ID must be updated to iOS 16.2, iPadOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.2, watchOS 9.2, and the latest version of iCloud for Windows. **This requirement prevents a previous version of iOS, iPadOS, macOS, tvOS, or watchOS from mishandling the newly-created service keys by re-uploading them to the available-after-authentication HSMs in a misguided attempt to repair the account state.**